# Bash script of history command redirection to a file in a docker container

Tags: linux, bash, docker

So i have this script that works fine in my host machine

```sh
#!/bin/bash -i
history > history.txt
```

but when i execute it in my docker container my history.txt looks like this : (it copies my script into the file and if i re-execute the script it does the same thing again !)

```
1  #!/bin/bash -i
2  history > history.txt
```

by the way when i execute "history > history.txt" directly from the terminal it works fine .

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

With `bash -i`, executed lines are logged in the history. You execute lines from your script, therefore the lines from your script show up in `history.txt`.

You can see this at the end of your history on the host as well:

```
$ tail -n 2 history.txt
29419  #!/bin/bash -i
29420  history > history.txt
```

In a clean Docker instance there is obviously no previous history, so those two lines are all you get:

```
$ tail -n 2 history.txt
    1  #!/bin/bash -i
    2  history > history.txt
```

There is no way to directly access your bash history outside of Docker from inside, so if that's what you want to do, you should dump it to a file first, and then give Docker access to this file.

Comment: i removed the -i and the script doesnt output anything , i've passed some commands in the terminal before executing the script and the "history" command shows those commands

Comment: Non-interactive shells do not have history. You can see this with `bash -c 'history'`. New interactive shell instances load history from `.bash_history`, which by default is only saved on logout.